# Rails update_attributes with dynamic hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, hash

I have a rails app in which I am trying to update a model with the attributes I am getting in the hash.

My code is:

```
attr_hash = {"name"=>"cat_name"}

@category.update_attributes(attr_hash, :type => 'sample')
```

Here is what I want that type will be fixed and the attr hash can be any attribute base on the form submit. But this gives me an error. Any ideas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
attr_hash = {"name"=>"cat_name"}

@category.update_attributes(attr_hash.merge(type: "sample"))
```

(because `update_attributes` takes only one hash)

Explanation:

Currently you're passing this:

`update_attributes({"name"=>"cat_name"}, {type: "sample"})`

but you want this:

`update_attributes({"name"=>"cat_name", type: "sample"})`

So you need to merge these two hashes.

Comment: I am getting ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError when trying to put the hash variable in the update method.

Comment: Does your @category have a `name` as well as a `type` column?
Please share the whole controller code. I assume you don't require the params you want to pass..
You have something like: `params["category"]["name"]` but you have to get it like this: `params.require(:category).permit(:name)`

Comment: i havent whitelisted the params .. my bad